# how to cleanly dispatch virtual calls from non templated parent to templated child

Tags: c++, templates

I have a really ugly implementation of something that I want to refactor but I am not sure how. Here is what I have:

Some templated object

```
template< typename T>
class Thing { };
```

An interface

```
class IService {
     public:
          virtual void func(void* arg) = 0;
};
```

A templated class implementing it

```
template< typename T>
class Service< T> : public IService {
     virtual void func(void* arg) {
          func((Thing< T>* )arg);
     }
     void func(Thing< T>* arg) {
          // do something with arg
     }
};
```

The reason is that I want a non-templated IService that I can pass around. templating IService will cause massive refactor through a large code base.

So instead, I instantiate Service< T> objects, pass around the IService, and call func with templated Thing objects, which does an ugly cast to a similar function that takes the actual Thing object. Is there any clean way to achieve this without templating IService?

Edit: some more context. This is what I really want:

```
template<typename T>
class IService {
     public:
          virtual void func(Thing<T>* arg) = 0;
};
```

However, I cannot template IService.

Comment: Could you provide more context on what you're trying to do?

Comment: So, any given `Service` must have the same `T` as the `Thing`? What if I call `Thing<double> t; myIService->func(t)` where `myIService` is a `Service<int>`?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo added

Comment: @David yes that would fail at runtime, however this code works for me because I always know the cast is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't want to or can't give `Thing` a base class, and given that a given `Service<T>` can only handle `Thing`s which have the same `T`, you could do this:

```
class IService {
     public:
        template <typename T>
        void func(Thing<T>* arg) {
            auto self = dynamic_cast<Service<T>*>(this);
            if (self) {
                self->func(arg);
            } else {
                // decide how to handle this error
            }
        }
};
```

`func` would not be virtual. It is just a template policy that deriving from IService needs to have a `func(Thing<T>*)` method.

Comment: This is a good answer in that it does not assume much else than what the OP said. However, self->func(arg) should be calling a different method because if Service<T> (which inherits from IService) does not have a func(arg) method of its own, it will call this one and get stuck in a recursive loop. By having a different method, you'll even get a compile-time check that Service<T> has the appropriate method

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some interface for the `Thing` would do the trick?

```
class IThing { };

template< typename T>
class Thing: public IThing { };

class IService {
     public:
          virtual void func(IThing* arg) = 0;
};

template< typename T>
class Service: public IService {
    virtual void func(IThing* arg) {
        Thing<T> *thing = dynamic_cast<Thing<T> *>(arg);
        if (thing) {
            // implementation
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to type-erase `Thing`'s `<T>` template parameter through the use of a non-templated `IService` class and that you do not care about `T` in the implementation of `IService`. I am not sure these assumption are correct, but here's a possible solution.

I'm also assuming that having `virtual` dispatch inside `Thing` suffice in your use case.

```
// Create a `ThingBase` class to "type-erase" `Thing`'s 
// template parameter. `ThingBase` should contain your
// `func`, as `virtual`.
struct ThingBase
{
    virtual void func();
};

// Your `Thing<T>` class should override `func`
template <typename T>
struct Thing : ThingBase
{
    void func() override { /* ... */ }
};

// Your `IService` now only needs to be as follows:
struct IService
{
    void func(ThingBase& x) 
    {
        x.func();
    }
};
```